# The probability that a 3-element subset selected at random from the set $\{1,2,3, … , 10\}$a)contains the integer $7$?(b)has 7 as its largest element?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> What is the probability that a 3-element subset selected at random from the set $\{1,2,3, … , 10\}$
>
> a) contains the integer $7$?
>
> b) has $7$ as its largest element?

I know this deals with permutation and combinations. For part a) I think it will be something like $\binom93$ but I'm not sure what to do with integer 7 and also for part b)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Number of ways to choose a 3 element set is $10 \choose 3$. For it to contain $7$ we have to choose 2 other integers from $9$ left. So, total number of sets where $7$ is chosen is $9 \choose 2$.

For $7$ to be the largest, you are picking $3$ elements from $\{1,2, \cdots, 7\}$ where $7$ has to be a part of the chosen set. Apply same techniques as above.

Comment: @user142743: It would be $6 \choose 2$ as $7$ has to be picked, so you are picking the other two numbers.